# Jmeter dashboards in s3 are not displaying properly

Tags: jmeter

I uploaded the jmeter dashboard to s3 bucket using JSR223 sampler with index.html and other folders.  when I open the index.html from s3 bucket, the dashboards are not displaying properly
It works properly fine when I open the same file locally( after downloading from s3) using a browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to make sure that **everything** has been uploaded, like

   - index.html
   - statistics.json
   - content
   - sbadmin2-1.0.7
2. You need to enable [static website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html):

   [image]
3. You need to [**make public** all objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html) (index.html and stuff)

   [image]
4. If there are no obvious errors in your Groovy script (hopefully you're using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)) you should be able to see your dashboard from AWS

   [image]

Comment: instead of making changes as static website. I was able to play with s3 policy and get the dashboard up. Thanks for your help.